# Custom tab for Spark Structured streaming UI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have created a Custom Streaming tab for Spark Structured streaming. I have just attached the streaming Tab in Spark UI but i am not able to attach page in streaming tab. In this custom tab, i want to show how many batches has completed, number of messages coming per batch, Processing Time and its graph. Through SQL listener and StreamingQueryListener i can get the information and want to add in streaming tab.

```
public class CustomTab extends SparkUITab {

public CustomTab(SparkUI parent, String prefix) {
    super(parent, prefix);
}

public static void getCustomTab(JobContext jobcontext) {
    SparkContext sparkContext = jobcontext.getSparkSession().sparkContext();

    StreamingContext ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, new Duration(1000));
    StreamingTab streamingTab = new StreamingTab(ssc);

    sparkContext.ui().get().attachPage(new CustomPage("customPage", streamingTab));

    if (sparkContext.ui().isDefined()) {
        sparkContext.ui().get().attachTab(streamingTab);

    } 
}
```

}

I am getting issue while attaching customPage in custom streaming tab. render method of SparkUITab is not called by SparkUI.
Second issue I am getting is that how to change scala.xml.Node class in Java. I mean is there any class in java that I can use instead of Node class or how to add String in scala.xml.Node.

If there is any Java class that I can use, so how to change back to Seq of Node.

```
class CustomPage extends WebUIPage {

StreamingTab streamingTab = null;

public CustomPage(String prefix, StreamingTab sparkUI) {
    super(prefix);
    this.streamingTab = sparkUI;
}

@Override
public Seq<Node> render(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("In render method");

    String value = "This text is going to come at the bottom";
    Option<String> optionSome = Option.apply(value);

    Function0<Seq<Node>> length = new AbstractFunction0<Seq<Node>>() {

        @Override
        public Seq<Node> apply() {
            scala.xml.Node node = null;
        //  I am not getting that how to add html code("<div> { <div id=\"custommmmmm\"></div> }  </div>") here
            return null;
        }

    };

    return UIUtils.headerSparkPage("custom", length, this.streamingTab, null, optionSome, false, false);
}
```

}

Is it possible to show structured streaming batches, its processing time and no of rows per batch through listeners and if possible then which listener should i use and how to add that in my custom page.

Comment: This isn't Structured Streaming by the way, you use the old RDD Streaming API

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamingQueryListener for your use case. You'll have to persist the data you get from StreamingQueryListener and then you can display them in your Custom tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class Text - see the example:

```
UIUtils.headerSparkPage(request,
                "My page",
                () -> new Text("my custom page content"), parent, Option.apply("help text"),false, false);
```